# how to automatic go to athor page, when success create account and set value at firebase database

Tags: javascript, html, firebase-authentication

i want make system, after success create an account and set value on Firebase database, it will go to the other page. i has set go to next page but, not set value into database. the think is, i want to make sure after create and set value to database and the system will move to another page.

```
    var  email = document.getElementById("email_field");
    var  password = document.getElementById("password_field");


      firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email.value, password.value).then(function(user)
      {
        var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
        if (firebase.auth().currentUser !== null)
            console.log("user id: " + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid);

        LogUser(user.uid);

        console.log("user id: " + user.uid);

      }).catch(function(error) {

    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    window.alert("Error : " + errorCode+"message"+errorMessage);

    if(err = null){

    }
    // ...
  });

  function LogUser(user){
      firebase.database().ref('tbluser').child(user).set({

        email: email,
        test:"ha"

      });

      location.replace("signin.html")
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the article [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#add_a_completion_callback) on how to use Firebase Database callbacks.

Your code should look something like this:

```js
firebase.database().ref('tbluser').child(user).set({
    email: email,
    test: "ha"
}, function(error) {
    if (error) {
        // it failed, do something here
    } else {
        // Data saved successfully!
        location.replace("signin.html")
    }
})
```

Good luck!